# On Windows Phone, can I view the source of a URL, if the URL itself is known?

Tags: url, windows-phone-7, html-parsing

and thanks for looking.

Imagine your standard barebones Windows Phone app. Say, I have a URL in mind. I want to be able to view the HTML source for that URL, because I'm looking for particular info that is on that page. Is there any way to do this?

Peace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull down the html for any page using HttpWebRequest. This project demonstrates that among other things.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)

If scraping data from webpages, be sure to verify the rights granted by the site's owner for that purpose.